# How to set env variable in local development for google cloud functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, environment-variables

I'm trying to run cloud function on my local system for which I need to set some env variables. I'm following [docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/env-var) for env and for local development [docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/running/function-frameworks).

I'm trying to run my project via the following command:

```
node node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework --target=syncingredients --env-vars-file=.env.yaml
```

Where my `.env.yaml` looks like:

```
API_KEY: key
AUTH_DOMAIN: project.firebaseapp.com
```

Comment: I think creating a package.json file with npm init, index.js file with your content, installing the functions framework using  `npm install @google-cloud/functions-framework` , adding start script to package.json, with configuration passed via command-line arguments like : `"start":"functions-framework --target=helloWorld --trigger-http --env-vars-file ./.env.yaml"` ( where .env.yaml has your environment variables set), then `npm start` can also achieve you the same

Comment: No It doesn't @PriyashreeBhadra if you look at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/issues/38 you'll find that it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Seems like --env-vars-file aren't supported with functions framework (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/issues/38)

I would recommend the workaround suggested by relymd-djk:

pre-req:

```
npm install env-cmd 
npm install yaml2json
```

modifying the package.json scripts section with:

```
"scripts": {
    "start":"yaml2json .env.yaml >.env.json && env-cmd -r ./.env.json functions-framework --target=syncingredients",
    "deploy": "gcloud functions deploy myFunction --entry-point syncingredients  --trigger-http --runtime nodejs16  --env-vars-file ./.env.yaml"
}
```

to run the function:

```
npm start
```

Comment: Thank you. Just upvoted and loved your answer but I'll go with dotenv for my project.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ClumsyPuffin for highlighting that it isn't an available feature so I went for [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Changed the file to `.env`:

```
API_KEY="key"
AUTH_DOMAIN="project.firebaseapp.com"
```

And used the following command to run the function locally

```
node -r dotenv/config node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework --target=syncingredients
```

Answer (score 0):

As reference, [This](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/how-to-develop-and-test-your-cloud-functions-locally) link helped me get it working, I leveraged env-cmd on top of the script's in this link. :

```
npm install env-cmd --save-dev
```

and then in the script I was able to feed the .env file prior to functions-the framework portion I used:

```
env-cmd -r ./.env
```

full working:

```
env-cmd -r ./.env node --inspect  node_modules/.bin/functions-framework --source=dist/ --target=testFunction
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Install [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd) as dev dependendy

```
npm i env-cmd --save-dev
```

2. Update `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "google-cloud-function",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^3.0.0",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd functions-framework --target=googleCloudFunction"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0"
  }
}
```

4. Create `.env` in root directory

```
ENV_VARIABLE_HAHA="hahahah"
ENV_VARIABLE_FOO="fooo"
```

5. In `index.js`

```js
'use strict';

console.log(process.env);

exports.googleCloudFunction= async (req, res) => {
  console.info('googleCloudFunction started...');
  try {
    const {ENV_VARIABLE_HAHA, ENV_VARIABLE_FOO} = process.env;
    console.log(ENV_VARIABLE_HAHA, ENV_VARIABLE_FOO);

    console.info('googleCloudFunction finished.');

    res.status(200).send(process.env);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    console.error('googleCloudFunctionfailed.');

    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
}
```